# Beginning-End regex conflict? Can't highlight last bracket

Tags: regex, notepad++, pcre

I am trying to highlight all declarations of the "navbar" class and all at-rules linked with it. I am failing with one bracket. 
I put " * " at the end to highlight all the remaining brackets but it didn't work for me. I assume that it has something in common with the possible conflict between first and the last part of the regex (same bracket). 
How should I proceed?

[The missing bracket.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9tNM.jpg)

My regex:

```
[^\}]*navbar[^\{]*\{[^\}]*\}*
```

...and the code

```
.dropup .caret,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .caret {
    content: "";
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 4px dashed;
    border-bottom: 4px solid\9
}
.dropup .dropdown-menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px
}
.dropup .dropdown-menu,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown .dropdown-menu {
    top: auto;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 2px
}
@media (min-width:768px) {
    .navbar-right .dropdown-menu {
        right: 0;
        left: auto
    }
    .navbar-right .dropdown-menu-left {
        right: auto;
        left: 0
    }
}
.btn-group,
.btn-group-vertical {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot about the whitespaces. `[^\}]*navbar[^\{]*\{[^\}]*[\}\s]*` solves your problem!